# ConstraintLayout wrap the background but constraint horizontally

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'd like to achieve a simple constraint layout that looks like this

[image]

The "Unknown length text", as it's self-explanatory, has an unknown length so it can be either 1 line or multiple lines. The implementation of the text looks like this

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/twelve_dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/four_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_transaction"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/flow_eight_dp"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/flow_two_dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue_100"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_info_2_description"
    tools:text="Unknown length text" />
```

This has no issue when the text is short, however, when the text becomes long it will not respect the constraint because I have not added the "end-to-end" constraint. So, it will become like this

[image]

This can be fixed by making the `layout_width="0dp"` and adding `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`. However, the problem is that the background will take up all the space when the text is short.

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/twelve_dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/four_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_transaction"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/eight_dp"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/two_dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue_100"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_info_2_description"
    tools:text="short text" />
```

Is there any way to use the advantage of `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` and make the textview's background only fill the text's width (like in the first screenshot)?

One way of course is to wrap the text view into a frame layout, but I am wondering is there any way to achieve it without an extra layout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you noticed, but the problem is that `android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/twelve_dp"` is shifting your textview to the right, therefore exceeding the constraint, when you did not explicitly set the constraint. You can either remove that or just set the end-to-end constraint.

You will also need to set the layout width of the textview to `wrap_content`, so it will conform to the length of the text in the textview.

Comment: I see your point that instead of horizontal margin in text view, I should add horizontal padding in the parent. Yes. this solves the problem. The reason I didn't do it is that I wanted to have a bigger area for click listener for "more info" text. So I have lots of padding around the "more info" text so It's easier to capture click event.